# How do I find out what constraints are on properties of objects in the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For example what is the character limit of the 'title' of an Event object. Or what data formats are allowed for the 'place' property of a Checkin. Can't find this is any of the online documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that there are a lot of open areas around the Facebook API.  Field limits being one of them.  One reason for the lack of field limits may be to the way Facebook manages their data.  Many of their input fields allow for extremely large inputs, if they are restricted at all.  Although, that obviously does not apply to all fields as you can see by just using their website.  If you max out their limit, you will typically be presented with a very basic error message.

From my own personal testing, I have found that the specific limit for the Event.title is 75 characters.

As for the place property, it is documented in the publishing section of the 'Checkin' object that the place parameter for a checking publish is the `ID of the PAGE` to which you are performing a checking.  It would be better for them to define the publish parameters in a similar fashion to the read object, but for some reason they did not do so.  As a result it is easy to confuse the two.

For most publishing operations you mostly want to look at the publishing examples at the bottom of the object documentation (Post, Checkin, etc) and then compare them with the descriptions of the read objects presented above.  Sometimes they are the same, but as in the case of Checkin, there can be differences.